# Python "keyboard" module: Release keys to allow copy/Ctrl+C

Tags: python, automation, keyboard-shortcuts, ui-automation, keyboard-events

I'm trying to simulate an existing AutoHotKey script using the "keyboard" module in Python (since the deployment story of AHK scripts seems to be even worse than Python scripts).

In this script, I use a keyboard shortcut (Left Windows key+F12), which should trigger the "copy" command, allowing me to retrieve the copied text via pyperclip or win32clipboard, modify it, and replace the selected text by typing new text

Here's the win32clipboard version of the code:

```py
import keyboard
import win32clipboard

def on_triggered():
    keyboard.press_and_release('ctrl+c')
    win32clipboard.OpenClipboard()
    new_data = win32clipboard.GetClipboardData()
    win32clipboard.CloseClipboard()
    keyboard.write(new_data + ' duuuuude.')

keyboard.add_hotkey('left windows+F12', on_triggered)
```

I've simplified the script above, removing some of the housekeeping code (saving, clearing and restoring the existing clipboard contents).

From what I can tell, when "ctrl+c" is triggered, "left windows+F12" is still held down, and the text never actually copies. Is there a way to tell the "keyboard" library to ignore all current keyboard input? Or am I taking the wrong approach?

Comment: did you  find a solution for this?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I think I’m going to try to figure out how to deploy AutoHotKey and modify AutoHotKey scripts with a Python script in order to do what I need to.

Comment: Actually I found a workaround, I just created a thread inside the callback function, I let the thread sleep for 0.3s then executed my code and it works just fine.

Comment: Nice! I’ve never used Python threads for anything useful, that should give me the motivation I need. Feel free to post that as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here you can use python's "PyAutoGui" module too.
It's very simple and very short to code.

Ex.

```
pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'c')  # ctrl-c to copy
pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'v')  # ctrl-v to paste
```

Comment: Thanks, I believe I tried pyautogui first, and it had the same issue that the keyboard module did. There needs to be some method of accepting the other key command I used and releasing those keys before executing the copy/paste.